# Changing key of dictionary while comparing its values (list) with another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

On one hand I have **1 dictionary** with 100 keys and behind each key there is a list with many more entries:

```
dict1 = {"/*** Hello1   ***/": ["1", "2", "3", "4"....],
         "/*** Hello2   ***/": ["1", "2", "3", "4"....]
         "/*** Hello2   ***/": ["1", "2", "3", "4"....]}
```

The keys of the dict are strings which have a weird looking syntax (out of .c file headers, thats why they have /*** in it).

On the other hand I have a list with all the key values of the dictionary in it but with only the core values:

```
list1 = ["Hello3", "Hello2", "Hello1"]
```

Both the dictionary and the list are unordered and it could be that the dict1 has keys in it, which the list1 does not contain!

Is there a fast way to compare the keys of the dict1 and the values of list1 and change the keys of the dict1 to the matched entries of list1?

Something like this?:

```
for x in list1:
   for y in dict1:
      if x in y:
         dict1[x] = dict1.pop(y)
```

Error: dictionary changed size during iteration

Don't get how I can fix it...

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Is it only possible by creating a new dictionary and simply adding the given values? Sorry for not mentioning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through a copy of your dict to avoid your specific problem:

```
for x in list1:
   for y in dict1.copy():
      if x in y:
         dict1[x] = dict1.pop(y)
```

Comment: Python is such a great language :D
Thanks a lot solved the problem perfectly!